# Is it correct ? "A vintage girl who came from 90s"

Tags: grammar

is it correct? "A vintage girl who came from 90s"

Comment: You don't need to mention the "90s". "*A vintage girl*" itself suggests that the girl is from the 70s/80s/90s. Unless you want to specifically mention which time period she comes from.

Comment: Improving the sentence - "*A vintage girl from the 90s.*" sounds better.

Comment: The 1990s are considered “vintage” now?!

Answer (score 0):

*A vintage girl from **the** 90's.*

This is the best way to write the sentence.

*"who came from"* is unnecessary. One thing about grammar is sweet but crisp sentences. 
However, the important thing is to precede the timeline with "the" and thus:

*A vintage girl who came from the 90's.*

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

Although we would say "a 90s girl", when using 'from' we would say "the 90s".

So :

```
"a vintage girl, from the 90s"
```

The comma is not strictly necessary, but it is more clear for some reason I can't  identify right now. I'll come back to it -- or maybe someone else?

Or you can also say:

```
"a 90's vintage girl"
```